# How to apply pattern matching in this case

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

How I can apply pattern-matching to this code? So it will looks like code written in functional style:

```
  def getIndex(i: Int): Option[Int] = {
    if (check0(i) == Some) {
      check0(i)
    }
    else if (check1(i) == Some) {
      check1(i)
    }
    else if (check2(i) == Some) {
      check2(i)
    }
    else if (check3(i) == Some) {
      check3(i)
    }
    else {
      None
    }
  }
```

Methods `check0, check1, check2, check3` all returns `Option[Int]`

Comment: Every single brace in your snippet is unnecessary!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a pattern matching, but should do the trick:

```
checkTop(clickedIndex)    orElse 
checkBottom(clickedIndex) orElse 
checkLeft(clickedIndex)   orElse 
checkRight(clickedIndex)
```

orElse is a method defined for [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option). When option is defined, it returns an option itself, otherwise it tries an alternative.

Comment: do you need the orElse None in the end?

Comment: @JensSchauder well, yeah, it is a little bit redundant

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def getIndex(i: Int) = check0(i) match {
  case None => check1(i) match {
    case None => check2(i) match {
      case None => check(3)
      case some2 => some2
    }
    case some1 => some1
  }
  case some0 => some0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not saying it's the simplest solution, but truly functional:

```
def multiCheck(checks: ((Int) => Option[Int])*)(i: Int) =
  checks.foldLeft[Option[Int]](None)(_ orElse _(i))

multiCheck(check0, check1, check2, check3)(2)
```